# 'NOT LIKE' in an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

Why does this simple query return 'ORA-00936: missing expression' (the database is Oracle as you can tell):

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id NOT LIKE '1%' AND NOT LIKE '2%'
```

I feel silly, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have missed out the field name `id` in the second `NOT LIKE`. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id NOT LIKE '1%' AND id NOT LIKE '2%'
```

The `AND` in the where clause joins 2 full condition expressions such as `id NOT LIKE '1%'` and can't be used to list multiple values that the id is 'not like'.

Answer (score 16):

You need to specify the column in both expressions.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id NOT LIKE '1%' AND id NOT LIKE '2%'
```

Answer (score 14):

You've missed the id out before the NOT; it needs to be specified.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id NOT LIKE '1%' AND id NOT LIKE '2%'
```

Answer (score 2):

After "AND" and after "OR" the QUERY has forgotten what it is all about.

I would also not know that it is about in any SQL / programming language.

if(SOMETHING equals "X" or SOMETHING equals "Y")

COLUMN NOT LIKE "A%" AND COLUMN NOT LIKE "B%"