# Create table - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create table, which should I call Others. I want only employeers who names which having names start with any other letter, but not K

I wrote sthg like this:

```
CREATE TABLE others AS select * from employees WHERE last_name no like 'K%';
```

I found sthg like this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762712/not-like-in-an-sql-query) but it doesn't work

I'm receiving errror about syntax. Can you help me?
The second question: there is any other way to write it?

Comment: **not** like...

Comment: Create a view instead. No need to store same data in several tables.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
CREATE TABLE others  AS (SELECT *
      FROM employees 
      WHERE last_name  NOT LIKE 'K%');
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jarlh said in his comment, a view would serve the same purpose, but the data would only be stored once instead of twice, thus saving disk space. You could define the view as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW OTHERS AS
  SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE LAST_NAME NOT LIKE 'K%';
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using just string functions.  Here are two ways:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1) <> 'K'
```

or:

```
WHERE last_name < 'K' or last_name >= 'L'
```

Although you can use `LIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE()` for this, I like this simpler approaches.